# What are some examples of C++1z axioms?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-concepts

C++1z should introduce concepts (constraints + axioms) into language. Except for those axioms already mentioned (reflexive, commutative, transitive), what are some other axioms that could be useful? Should axioms be used only for compiler optimisations, or could they work for different purpose as well?

Comment: They won't be introduced in future versions of C++ at all?

Comment: I don't know about that, but the current concept paper doesn't include then, so don't anticipate axioms to be in C++1Z.-

Comment: Axioms are a harder problem than constraints because they have to be verified at runtime. A solution was found for constraints that did not significantly affect compilation times and had no impact on runtime performance. Since axioms require a runtime hit, there's a lot more debate to be had and designs to consider. Maybe we'll end up taking a leaf out of the Contracts book, which has the same problem, including cases where checking a contract can have a higher order time complexity than the function itself (e.g., checking that a sequence is sorted before doing a binary search).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because axioms are definitely not a thing in C++17 now, and this question has become irrelevant. At least, it needs to examine more recent proposals of preconditions etc.